# AppleScript : calcule how many day from two date

Tags: date, applescript

I need to calculate the date between two dates, and tell me how many day are in between, if more than 30 days then I will target something.

in this script D is the date (in the past) that I want to calculate from today

```
  set X to MYdatefromSafari -- "August 26th, 2016"

    set D to ConvertDate(X)
    log D


    on ConvertDate(X) -- sub routine to convert string "english_month dayth/st, year" to real date
        set MS to {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
        set LW to every word of X
        if (count of LW) is not 3 then return "" -- invalid format
        set MI to 0 -- check month : should be in the list
        repeat with I from 1 to 12
            if item I of MS is item 1 of LW then set MI to I
        end repeat
        if MI is 0 then return "" -- the fisrt word is not in the list of months    
        try -- check day : it should be NNth of NNst
            set DI to (text 1 thru -3 of item 2 of LW) as integer
        end try
        if not ((DI > 0) and (DI < 31)) then return "" -- invalid day
        try -- check year
            set YI to (item 3 of LW) as integer
        end try
        if not ((YI > 0) and (YI < 9999)) then return "" -- invalid year
        return date ((DI & "/" & MI & "/" & YI) as string)
    end ConvertDate


In the best scenario, that would calculate the number of date in between if less than a year, and month or year if more 


EDIT :
set X to "August 26th, 2016"
set MyDate to ConvertDate(X)

set D to ConvertDate(X)
log D

set SecondDate to (current date) -- = system date
set ListDiff to DateDiff(D, CD) -- returns {diff days, diff months, diff years}
log "Days = " & item 1 of ListDiff
log "Months = " & item 2 of ListDiff
log "Years = " & item 3 of ListDiff

on DateDiff(D1, D2) -- return list with difference in days, in months, in years
    -- depending if differences is less than month, or less than year or higher than a year
    if D1 > D2 then -- set DStart as oldest date
        copy {D1, D2} to {Dend, DStart}
    else
        copy {D1, D2} to {DStart, Dend}
    end if
    return {(Dend - DStart) div days, (Dend - DStart) div (30 * days), (Dend - DStart) div (365 * days)}
end DateDiff

on ConvertDate(X) -- sub routine to convert string "english_month dayth/st, year" to real date
    set MS to {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
    set LW to every word of X
    if (count of LW) is not 3 then return "" -- invalid format
    set MI to 0 -- check month : should be in the list
    repeat with I from 1 to 12
        if item I of MS is item 1 of LW then set MI to I
    end repeat
    if MI is 0 then return "" -- the fisrt word is not in the list of months    
    try -- check day : it should be NNth of NNst
        set DI to (text 1 thru -3 of item 2 of LW) as integer
    end try
    if not ((DI > 0) and (DI < 31)) then return "" -- invalid day
    try -- check year
        set YI to (item 3 of LW) as integer
    end try
    if not ((YI > 0) and (YI < 9999)) then return "" -- invalid year
    return date ((DI & "/" & MI & "/" & YI) as string)
end ConvertDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Sub-routine "DateDiff" bellow gives back a list of 3 difference values : in days, months and years.

```
Set X to MyDatefrom Safari
Set MyDate to ConvertDate(X)

set SecondDate to (current date) -- = system date
set ListDiff to DateDiff(D, CD) -- returns {diff days, diff months, diff years}
log "Days = " & item 1 of ListDiff
log "Months = " & item 2 of ListDiff
log "Years = " & item 3 of ListDiff

on DateDiff(D1, D2) -- return list with difference in days, in months, in years
-- depending if differences is less than month, or less than year or higher than a year
if D1 > D2 then -- set DStart as oldest date
    copy {D1, D2} to {Dend, DStart}
else
    copy {D1, D2} to {DStart, Dend}
end if
return {(Dend - DStart) div days, (Dend - DStart) div (30 * days), (Dend - DStart) div (365 * days)}
end DateDiff

on ConvertDate(X) -- copy your existing sub-routine
end ConvertDate
```

For instance if MyDate = Jan 20th 2016 and we are August 26th 2016, it will return {219, 7, 0} because différence is 216 days or 7 months (Jan to August) or 0 year (2016 both dates !).

Comment: That look good, thank you. I have a error though, variable CD is not defined, I edited the original post with the full script